# How to configure git to show log graph without wrapping long commit messages

Tags: git

My git graph now looks like this
[image]

and this looks very bad and unpleasant for me
Is there a way to force git to not wrapping long lines and use horizontal scrolling instead?

Comment: "horizontal scrolling", isn't that a feature of the console or shell you're using, and not git? On second thought, it does provide up/down scrolling, I think this is the `less` command

Comment: Maybe so, my question is still relevant, I want to get rid of the wrapping

Comment: I don't think you can, I don't think less has support for this, you're probably better off getting a UI client for git for this, or find out if there's something other than less that can be used. Git can be configured to use a custom paging application.

Comment: I don't think this is a programming question.

Comment: Hm, try this: `git config --global core.pager 'less -S'`. Execute `git config core.pager` first to see what your current value is, in case you need to restore it.

Comment: Or `export LESS=S`

Answer (score 5):

Most likely, you are using `less` as the pager. It allows to change line folding on the fly. Just type `-S`, i.e., <kbd>-</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, and then, if you are asked to press <kbd>Return</kbd>, do that. This switches between wrapped lines and truncated lines.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to extending the horizontal span, you can use the specific [format construct](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt-emltltNgttruncltruncmtruncem) `%<(N,trunc)` to truncate commit messages and fit your screen. (where N is the number of chars for the column)

Just an example, feel free to adapt the colors and the column widths to suit your needs

```
git config --global alias.fl 'log --graph --pretty=format:"%C(green)%h %C(yellow)%<(16,trunc)%aN %C(red)%<(12,trunc)%ar %C(reset)%<(135,trunc)%s"'

git fl
```

Comment: You're right, I'll rephrase this as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to force git to not wrapping long lines

Yes, as mentioned by [@Romain Valeri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1057485/romain-valeri), the format specification can be used to truncate lines. However, if the width specifier isn't appropriately matched to the width of the terminal window, you may still get line wrapping.

As described in the [pretty-formats](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats#Documentation/pretty-formats.txt-emltltMgtem) documentation,

> *%<|( <M> )*
>
> make the next placeholder take at least until Mth
>    display column, padding spaces on the right if necessary.
>    *Use negative M values for column positions measured
>    from the right hand edge of the terminal window.*

To effectively turn off line wrapping, add `%<|(-1,trunc)` before the final placeholder in your format specification. For example, the command

```
git log --format='%C(auto)%h %d %gd %s'
```

will not have line wrapping, but the following command will.

```
git log --format='%C(auto)%h %d %gd %<|(-1,trunc)%s'
```